# Restrict client access in a single realm with keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a single realm with 3 single-page applications and a shared backend. I want to restrict the access to one of the SPAs so that users without a specific role can't log in.

But once you create a user in the realm, he can log in to every SPA client. I can restrict the endpoints of the backend but I don't want to programmatically reject the user in the specific SPA but automatically on the login page.

I tried to use client roles which don't seem to have an effect in this case. The only solution I have found so far is to create separate realms which I think is conceptually the correct way but unfortunately brings up some practical issues, e.g. the administrators of one realm must be able to manage (CRUD) users of another realm which seems fairly unintuitive.

Comment: `I want to restrict the access to one of the SPAs so that users without a specific role can't log in.` This seems a design issue. How would you know a user cannot access the SPA even before he gets logged in?

Comment: The exact issue I am facing! No one talks about it either. To me it doesn't seems like a design issue, because there is one to one relation between the `clients <-->users<-->roles`. The worst part is that, even without any role assignment, user from the realm can login to the different clients of the same realm which is just frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

`users without a specific role can't log in` - it isn't good requirement. How system will known if user has a specific role without log in (authentication)? Keycloak provides `Open ID Connect` SSO protocol, which is designated for authentication. After successful OIDC authentication is token generated, which may contains also user role. So only then authorization can be applied. So let's change requirement to: `users without a specific role can't access SPA`, which better fits into OIDC concept.

The mature OIDC SPA libraries offer `authorization guard` (name can differs, it is some kind of post login function), where authorization can be implemented. Authorization requires to have a specific role in the token usually, otherwise user is redirected to the custom route, e.g.`/unauthorized`. That's the page, where you can say a reason for denying access. Common use case is also customization of the app based on the user roles. For example users with admin role will see more items in the menu than standard users - that's also kind of authorization. Random example of SPA library with authorization guard (I'm not saying that's a best implementation) - https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/441

Keep in mind that SPA is not "secure" - user may tamper code/data in the browser, so in theory user may skip any authorization in the browser. He may get access to SPA, so it's is important to have proper authorization also on the backend (API) side. Attacker may have an access to SPA, but it will be useless if API denies his requests.

BTW: You can find hackish advices on the internet how to add authorization to the Keycloak client with custom scripting (e.g. custom scripted mapper, which will test role presence). That is terrible architecture approach - it is solving authorization in the authentication process. It won't be clear why user can't log in - if it is because credentials are wrong or because something requires some role in the authentication process.

Answer (score 3):

You should indeed not create multiple realms, since that is besides the point of SSO systems. Two approaches are possible in your - presumably - OAuth 2.0 based setup:

1. restrict access at the so-called Resource Server i.e your backend
2. use a per-SPA "scope" for each SPA that is sent in the authentication request

The first is architecturally sound but perhaps less preferred in some use cases as you seem to indicate. The second approach is something that OAuth 2.0 scopes were designed for. However, due to the nature of SPAs it is considered less secure since easier to spoof.

Comment: I very much agree with the first alinea in Jan Garaj's answer providing the conceptual background of my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restrict users access to application using following approach:

1. I've created to clients in my default realm (master) i called my clients test_client1 and test_client2 both of them are OIDC clients with confidential access by secret
2. I've created a role for each of them, i.e. i have role test_client1_login_role for test_client1 and test_client2_login_role for test_client2.
   [image]
3. I've created a two users - user1 and user2 and assign them to client 1 and client2 role. But to restrict access to client1 i have to delete default roles:
   [image]
4. That did the trick, when i am logging with user2 i see test_client2 and not test_client1 as available application:
   [image]
   But i did n't delete roles from user1 and therefore i could see both clients when i am log in with user1:
   [image]

Therefore you should use different clients for your applications, assign to each of a client specific role and remove from users default roles and add one releted to specific application.