# How to add the notion of "accounts" to Keycloak?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, openid

How do I best configure [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) so that a user needs to have an **account** for a client to be able to login into that client?

I have to replace a proprietory SSO-Impl. It deals with users, roles and clients much like Keycloak. However, it also knows about accounts. **A user is only allowed to login to a client if he has an account for that client.**

In Keycloak, if a user simply exists in a realm he may login to a client of that realm. Nothing else is needed. So no *"account"* is needed. In the old application, he needs an account as well.
**What functionality in Keycloak is best suited to overcome this difference?**

---

I have one idea:

Create a client-role in each client namend "HasAccount" and assign it to users. Then, restrict access if that role is missing.
This is discussed here: "[Restrict client access in a single realm with keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65769083/280244)"
It has at least two drawbacks:

- It mixes authentication and authorization in the legacy app. I can understand that. But creating a role was already a workaround. That is why I described my initial problem here.
- **I have clients in 3+ languages/technologies. Adding functionality there seems like more work than in Keycloak.**

---

*Last remark:*

*Before you ask "This is not single sign on" anymore. It is only for administrative purposes. The admin can allow users to login into a client or not by creating an account or not. The user does not have to login a second time. If he is logged in in App A and has an account for App B, accessing App B works without logging in there.*

Answer (score 2):

`A user is only allowed to login to a client if he has an account for that client.` is really not a task for Identity Provider (IdP). It provides only identity and not authorization.

Of course you can ignore that and implement authorization as well. See: [User attribute based web service access control by Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331061/user-attribute-based-web-service-access-control-by-keycloak)

From the design perspective I would add auth reverse proxy in front of legacy app (but it isn't a best solution for SPA apps). Auth proxy will provide authentication via OIDC protocol and also authorization. Legacy apps may keep own OIDC authentication - it will be seamless auth from the user perspective, because SSO will be used.

`Account` entity - you can use `group` entity in the Keycloak instead of original `account`.